# How to refresh a div with Jquery with symfony 4?

Tags: jquery, twig, symfony4

I am a beginner with symfony4.
I have a problem, I want to refresh my div(#test) without refreshing the entire page.
I'm asking for help to help me find the solution.
////////////////////////////controller//////////////////////////////////////

```
enter code here

  class HotFreezeController extends AbstractController
  {
/**
 * @Route("/hotfreeze", name="hot_freeze")
 */
public function index()
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(GestionTemperature::class);
    $temperatures = $repo->findAll();
    return $this->render('hot_freeze/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'HotFreezeController',
        'temperatures' => $temperatures,
    ]);
}
```

}

/////////////////////////////////////index.html.twig///////////////////////////

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
  {% block title %}Hello HotFreezeController!{% endblock %}
  {% block body %}
    <div id="test">
     {% for temp in temperatures %}
     <p> Thermostat n°{{temp.id}} :   {{temp.getTemperature()}}°C  
     {{temp.getConsommation()}}W.h {{temp.getStatut()}} 
     </p>
     {% endfor %}
    </div>
 <script>
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Take out that {%for%} outside, make function in controller which render it, call your ajax, return rendered html, replace innerHTML of div#test